# VBA - Use same variables in more modules

Tags: vba, excel, module

I want three modules that are summarized like that:

FIRST MODULE

```
Sub settings()
 Dim variable1,variable2,variable3,_
  variable4,variable5,variable6 as String

 variable1="Stack"
 variable2="Overflow"
 variable3="Best"
 variable4="Site"
 variable5="Ever"
 variable6="I love it!"
End sub
```

SECOND MODULE

```
Sub module2()
 'LINE CODE THAT CALLS "settings" MODULE (I want to know it!)

 'my sub that uses the six-variables above
End sub
```

THIRD MODULE

```
Sub module3()
 'LINE CODE THAT CALLS "settings" MODULE (I want to know it!)

 'another sub that uses the six-variables above
End sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Fabio

Comment: Look at the `Global` keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that these variables will always hold the same value, if that is the case then I suggest to declare public constants instead using the code below (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264636.aspx)

```
Public Const kConst1 As String = "Stack"
Public Const kConst2 As String = "Overflow"
Public Const kConst3 As String = "Best"
Public Const kConst4 As String = "Site"
Public Const kConst5 As String = "Ever"
Public Const kConst6 As String = "I love it!"
```

Used the constants as:

```
Sub Test_Const()
Debug.Print kConst1, kConst2, kConst3, kConst4, kConst5, kConst6
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have the modules as :

Module 1:

```
Public variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4, variable5, variable6 As String
Sub settings()
  variable1 = "Stack"
  variable2 = "Overflow"
  variable3 = "Best"
  variable4 = "Site"
  variable5 = "Ever"
  variable6 = "I love it!"
End Sub
```

Module 2:

```
Sub module2()
  Module1.settings
  MsgBox "value : " & Module1.variable1

End Sub
```

In Module 2, you will have to first run `settings()` subroutine, then use the variables, as the assignment to variables is happening in `settings()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't use 'Public ... as ... '

Comment: You should be aware that the first statement declares first 5 variables as `Variant`, last one as `String`

Comment: Also, if the variable is declared with Public scope then you don't need to qualify it with a module code name as it should have a unique name anyway.